# Asymptotic Difference of Binomial Expansions

Tags: limits, asymptotics, binomial-theorem

Given $x\rightarrow\infty$, I know that $(1-\frac{2\ln2}{x})^{x-2}-(1-\frac{\ln2}{x})^{2(x-1)}$ goes to zero because
\begin{align*}
\Big(1-\frac{2\ln2}{x}\Big)^{x-2}-\Big(1-\frac{\ln2}{x}\Big)^{2(x-1)}
&\sim\exp\Big(-\frac{2\ln2}{x}\cdot x\Big)-\exp\Big(-\frac{\ln2}{x}\cdot 2x\Big) \\
&=0,
\end{align*}
where I used $\sim$ to mean asymptotic equivalence. How can I find the specific scaling (i.e., the rate of convergence) of the difference?

From the plots I made, it seems to me that it should be something like $O(\frac{1}{x})$, which can be further verified with Wolfram alpha's Big-O domination [calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=57ad04c0f04cc92e742205985c18023e) -- the result is
\begin{align*}
\Big(1-\frac{2\ln2}{x}\Big)^{x-2}-\Big(1-\frac{\ln2}{x}\Big)^{2(x-1)}
&=\frac{\ln4-\ln^22}{4x}-O\Big(\frac{1}{x^2}\Big) \\
&=O\Big(\frac{1}{x}\Big).
\end{align*}
I tried using Binomial expansions and Taylor expansions but had trouble simplifying. Is there a simpler way to do this (without having to resort to Laurent series which Wolfram claims)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$$A=\left(1-\frac{2 \log (2)}{x}\right)^{x-2}\implies \log(A)=(x-2)\log\left(1-\frac{2 \log (2)}{x}\right)$$

So, by Taylor
$$\log(A)=-2\log (2)-\frac{2 ((\log (2)-2) \log (2))}{x}-\frac{4 \left(\log ^2(2) (2\log
   (2)-3)\right)}{3 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$
$$A=e^{\log(A)}=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{(\log (2)-2) \log (2)}{2 x}+\frac{\log ^2(2) (18+\log (2) (3\log
   (2)-16))}{6 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

Doing the same with

$$B=\left(1-\frac{\log (2)}{x}\right)^{2 (x-1)}$$
$$B=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{2\log (2)-\log ^2(2)}{4 x}+\frac{\log ^2(2) (18+\log (2) (3\log
   (2)-16))}{24 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

$$A-B=\frac{(2-\log (2)) \log (2)}{4 x}+\frac{\log ^2(2) \left(18+3 \log ^2(2)-16 \log
   (2)\right)}{8 x^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$

Using your pocket calculator with $x=100$, the exact result is
$0.00231558$ while the truncated expression gives
$0.00231476$.

Comment: May I ask what expansion did you use for the 3rd line (i.e., $A=e^{\log A}=\dots$ line)? Is it $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\dots$?

Answer (score 2):

An alternative (to the binomial series) is to use $(1-a/x)^{bx-c}=e^{(bx-c)\log(1-a/x)}$, i.e. take the power series for $\log(1-z)$ at $z=a/x$, multiply it by $(bx-c)$, and exponentiate the result (as a power series in $1/x$). Only the last step is nontrivial, especially if you need more than just the main term of the resulting asymptotics, but it can be done [mechanically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_formula) (if you don't need the full expansion in closed form).

Comment: Thanks. An explanation of the non-trivial step (the exponentiating step) would be helpful.

Comment: Now it is essentially done by @Claude (+1).